# Scraping WSJ.com using Rvest

Tags: html, r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the first table in the Wall Street Journal Markets Diary page ('https://www.wsj.com/market-data/stocks/marketsdiary') and it seems that rvest is not picking up the table in the html. Here's my code:

```
require(rvest)
require(dplyr)

wsj_html <- read_html('https://www.wsj.com/market-data/stocks/marketsdiary')
nyse_tbl = wsj_html %>% html_nodes('body') %>% html_nodes('div') %>% html_nodes('table') %>% html_nodes('tbody')
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `httr2` or `jsonlite` to get the source.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

'https://www.wsj.com/market-data/stocks/marketsdiary?id={"application":"WSJ","marketsDiaryType":"diaries"}&type=mdc_marketsdiary' %>%
  fromJSON() %>% 
  .$data %>%  
  as_tibble() %>%  
  unnest(instrumentSets) %>%  
  unnest(headerFields) %>%  
  unnest(instruments) 

# A tibble: 212 x 8
   value label id              name                 latestClose previousClose weekAgo     timestamp            
   <chr> <chr> <chr>           <chr>                <chr>       <chr>         <chr>       <chr>                
 1 name  NYSE  issuestraded    Issues traded        3,385       3,407         3,344       Friday, July 08, 2022
 2 name  NYSE  advances        Advances             1,497       2,494         2,412       Friday, July 08, 2022
 3 name  NYSE  declines        Declines             1,708       752           805         Friday, July 08, 2022
 4 name  NYSE  unchanged       Unchanged            180         161           127         Friday, July 08, 2022
 5 name  NYSE  newhighs        New highs            7           11            12          Friday, July 08, 2022
 6 name  NYSE  newlows         New lows             56          59            205         Friday, July 08, 2022
 7 name  NYSE  advvolume       Adv. volume*         283,922,224 785,792,562   693,314,370 Friday, July 08, 2022
 8 name  NYSE  declvolume      Decl. volume*        483,599,683 104,114,907   203,789,292 Friday, July 08, 2022
 9 name  NYSE  totalvolume     Total volume*        777,515,857 892,767,579   919,812,639 Friday, July 08, 2022
10 name  NYSE  closingarmstrin Closing Arms (TRIN)† 1.20        0.38          1.02        Friday, July 08, 2022
# ... with 202 more rows
```

Alternatively, you can do it with `RSelenium` to get the tables as they are displayed on the website.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)
library(netstat)

rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port = free_port())
remDr <- rD[["client"]]


remDr$navigate("https://www.wsj.com/market-data/stocks/marketsdiary")
source <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

source %>%
  read_html() %>%  
  html_table()

[[1]]
# A tibble: 57 x 4
   ``           `Latest Close` `Previous Close` `Week Ago`
   <chr>        <chr>          <chr>            <chr>     
 1 NYSE         Latest Close   Previous Close   Week Ago  
 2 Issues trad~ 3,385          3,407            3,344     
 3 Advances     1,497          2,494            2,412     
 4 Declines     1,708          752              805       
 5 Unchanged    180            161              127       
 6 New highs    7              11               12        
 7 New lows     56             59               205       
 8 Adv. volume* 283,922,224    785,792,562      693,314,3~
 9 Decl. volum~ 483,599,683    104,114,907      203,789,2~
10 Total volum~ 777,515,857    892,767,579      919,812,6~
# ... with 47 more rows

[[2]]
# A tibble: 15 x 4
   ``           `Latest Close` `Previous Close` `Week Ago`
   <chr>        <chr>          <chr>            <chr>     
 1 9:30 to 10:~ 96,773,796     118,483,423      112,076,7~
 2 10:00 to 10~ 43,263,747     48,247,363       56,369,510
 3 10:30 to 11~ 42,167,828     43,369,860       52,631,721
 4 11:00 to 11~ 31,750,172     37,432,262       41,812,829
 5 11:30 to 12~ 30,210,840     30,206,282       33,446,092
 6 12:00 to 12~ 26,258,430     26,547,120       28,841,126
 7 12:30 to 1:~ 26,284,237     28,346,311       28,485,375
 8 1:00 to 1:30 23,472,776     25,659,220       23,808,690
 9 1:30 to 2:00 22,194,379     24,886,867       29,124,176
10 2:00 to 2:30 22,060,112     29,228,153       30,130,702
11 2:30 to 3:00 23,046,855     28,545,060       28,604,043
12 3:00 to 3:30 29,926,731     34,514,543       35,432,016
13 3:30 to 4:00 360,105,954    417,301,115      419,049,6~
14 Total        777,515,857    892,767,579      919,812,6~
15 Composite    3,528,791,070  4,143,550,789    4,058,101~

[[3]]
# A tibble: 13 x 2
   NYSE          `Weekly Totals`
   <chr>         <chr>          
 1 Issues Traded 3,596          
 2 Advances      1,895          
 3 Declines      1,583          
 4 Unchanged     118            
 5 New Highs     26             
 6 New Lows      439            
 7 Adv Vol       8,276,302,604  
 8 Decl Vol      8,778,273,923  
 9 Total Vol     17,281,584,001 
10 zAdv Vol      1,804,202,853  
11 zDecl Vol     2,062,552,502  
12 zTotal Vol    3,906,549,612  
13 zBlock trades 17,798         

[[4]]
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   NASDAQ        `Weekly Totals`
   <chr>         <chr>          
 1 Issues Traded 5,443          
 2 Advances      3,360          
 3 Declines      1,842          
 4 Unchanged     241            
 5 New Highs     90             
 6 New Lows      734            
 7 Adv Vol       12,698,953,908 
 8 Decl Vol      6,133,314,084  
 9 Total Vol     19,061,277,371 
10 Block Trades  129,878        

[[5]]
# A tibble: 13 x 2
   `NYSE American` `Weekly Totals`
   <chr>           <chr>          
 1 Issues Traded   304            
 2 Advances        157            
 3 Declines        135            
 4 Unchanged       12             
 5 New Highs       0              
 6 New Lows        54             
 7 Adv Vol         598,998,905    
 8 Decl Vol        333,274,395    
 9 Total Vol       943,830,187    
10 zAdv Vol        33,061,561     
11 zDecl Vol       25,092,175     
12 zTotal Vol      58,995,872     
13 zBlock trades   598            

[[6]]
# A tibble: 13 x 2
   `NYSE Arca`   `Weekly Totals`
   <chr>         <chr>          
 1 Issues Traded 1,917          
 2 Advances      1,087          
 3 Declines      813            
 4 Unchanged     17             
 5 New Highs     16             
 6 New Lows      450            
 7 Adv Vol       3,060,741,851  
 8 Decl Vol      3,291,369,981  
 9 Total Vol     6,456,858,700  
10 zAdv Vol      561,643,211    
11 zDecl Vol     598,770,457    
12 zTotal Vol    1,176,719,093  
13 zBlock trades 4,673
```